# Safely dealing with an "open ground" temporarily

Tags: electrical, grounding

We have a few outlets with an open ground (the power does work). But because of the bad heat right now, I can't ask an electrician to go up in the attic to investigate until the winter.

I'd like to run a 1000W AC off this 20A open ground circuit. But due to the issue, I have a short (15A) extension to a different outlet on a different circuit with a working ground. Also not ideal - it's just a 15A circuit and other stuff is on there such as LED lights which don't like to stay on when the compressor kicks in.

1. Is there any safety issue if I just put the AC on the open ground circuit, or am I just risking the electronics of the AC itself?
2. As a temporary measure, would it be safe to get two grounding adapters, plug them both in separate outlets, run a makeshift ground wire between the grounding attachments on them, and then plug the AC into the technically open-ground 20A circuit? Really stupid idea or acceptable for a month or two?

Alternatively I could just keep it on the 15A circuit it's on now and put up with the lights blinking, but I'm not entirely sure of the safety or stupidity of that choice either.

Comment: Are any of the problem circuits protected by a GFCI?

Comment: There are inherent safety issues with ungrounded electrical equipment. They are why grounding has been mandated in the first place. You can install GFCI receptacles in your ungrounded outlet boxes, and plug your AC into one of those.

Comment: Does your AC have the giant "GFCI-like" plug on the end of its cord (similar to what you'd find on the end of a hair dryer)?

Comment: The answer to call an electrician anyway is the correct one. Tangent: if this is one of those awful portable AC units, and you can fit a window unit instead, do it. They work better, and one with the same real-world cooling capacity will use half the power.

Comment: No GFCI built in but I think the AC plug has one. I guess a moot point anyway if we're just going to call the electrician and hope they can be done before it starts cooking up there. Does the GFCI built in mean it's safe to use the other circuit until the electrician arrives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call the electrician anyway. They have super-powers which allow them to work in attics, known as "come in the morning" :)

The heat in your attic is not from ambient air temperature.  It is from "solar gain", which is is about 300 BTUs per square foot of square-on sunlight, *but is nonexistent at night*.  In the morning the attic will be perfectly usable.